# Pokemon Go Data Lost

Tags: pokemon-go

I broke my phone recently, and have to use my girlfriend's old Android for the time being. I installed Pokemon Go and tried using my Google account to sign in. I was level 20 and had previously bought store items with real money.
However, I am sent back to the starting screen with Professor Willow when I logged in. When picking a username, my previous username was already taken, so I know it's still there.

!!!The problem is that everyone is saying that I'm using a different email account than what I originally used. But I only have 1 Google account, and do not have a Pokemon trainer account. There is no possible way I'm using the wrong email, because, like I said, I only have one. There are no backups or linked accounts.

I've tried closing and refreshing the app, uninstall and reinstalling it, clearing the data, nothing is working.

How do I get my information back?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would make any difference, but have you tried changing `googlemail.com` to `gmail.com` (or vice versa) when connecting your Google account to the phone? Maybe the database does not identify Google accounts but unique mail addresses instead. Just an idea, nevermind if I'm wrong.

Comment: This might be caused by their one phone - one account rule, so it thinks you are a new player since you're using a different phone. If this is the case, you might need to contact customer support as I'm not sure what else you could do in this situation.